# Wait for jPlayer to finish loading files before continuing loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm using the jQuery audio player 'jPlayer', I have a loop which creates a number of jPlayer unique instances then assigns an on click 'jPlayer play' to another part of the document for each instance.. The problem is jPlayer uses an internal `ready: function() {}` to assign the audio path and load the file.. I need to wait for this function to finish before continuing the loop.

The pseudocode is something like this:

```
for loop{

create jPlayer div;

instantiate jPlayer and assign audio file in the ready(); // need to wait before continuing

assign an on click event to play file;
}
```

<strike>I'm convinced it's about using queues but I wouldn't know how to implement it? Any help would be most appreciated!</strike>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
function initPlayer(playerQueue){
  if(playerQueue.length > 0) {
    var player = playerQueue.pop(); // get our options hash for this iteration
    var container = $('<div id="'+player.container+'"></div>').appendTo('body');

    $(container).jPlayer({
      ready: function(){
        var _e = this.element;
        _e.jPlayer('setFile', player.file);
        var timer = setInterval(function(){
            if(_e.jPlayer('getData', 'diag.loadPercent') == 100){
               $(player.control).click(function(){
                  // assign your handler
               });
               clearInterval(timer); // clear the interval
               initPlayer(playerQueue); // invoke the next player init
            }
        },500);
      },
      /* ... other options ... */
    });
  }
}

initPlayer([
  {container: 'audio-1', file: 'uri/for/file', control: '#button-1'},
  {container: 'audio-2', file: 'uri/for/file', control: '#button-2'},
  {container: 'audio-3', file: 'uri/for/file', control: '#button-3'},
  {container: 'audio-4', file: 'uri/for/file', control: '#button-4'}
]);
```

Basically we get rid of the explicit loop and instead use the ready function itself to advance the build iteration via the `initPlayer` function. By usin an array we can use `pop()` which will get us that last element of the array while also removing it from the array. We wait to invoke `initPlayer` until after we get a load percent of 100 by polling the load percent of the player every 500 ms.

This is only a suggestion and may need a lot of work... ive never used jPlayer and am flying blind from the documentation so dont expect it to work out of the box :-).

Comment: You're an absolute genius! Thanks so much for this I really appreciate it, I had to mess around with it a little bit, add jPlayer('load'); after we specify the file path to actually load it.. and jPlayer likes to return 99.9999999 instead of 100 which is odd. I am getting an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'container' of undefined" every time (line 4 on your code snippet). Will get to the bottom of that though hopefully.. thanks again! (:

Comment: hmm throw in a `console.log(player); console.log(playerQueue);` just before the line with the `div` creation for debugging in Firefox/Firebug and see what the contents of each are. that error would worry me that there are scope issues which would be a big problem with this approach. they could probably be solved though by attaching your array of objects to the `window`object explicitly and calling it explicity as such :-)

Comment: Ahh just did what you said, for some reason I'd removed the if(playerQueue.length > 0).. so it was trying to process the empty array. Thanks for that :) !!